# AttributeError when returning Response with data that comes from a model property?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Full error I get is this one.

```
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `name` on serializer `AccountSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Ledger` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Ledger' object has no attribute 'name'.
```

This is the Account model containing the transfers property method I am trying to use.

```
class Account(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    is_loan = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    @classmethod
    def create_account(cls, user, name):
        cls(user=user, name=name).save()

    @property
    def balance(self):
        return Ledger.objects.filter(account=self.pk).aggregate(models.Sum('amount'))['amount__sum'] or '0'

    @property
    def transfers(self):
        return Ledger.objects.filter(account=self.pk).order_by("-timestamp")[:10]

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user} – {self.name} – {self.pk} – {self.is_loan}"
```

This is my serializer class.

```
class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = '__all__'
```

And here is the view method.

```
class Transactions(APIView):
    def get(self, request, pk):
        account = Account.objects.get(pk=pk)
        transactions = account.transfers
        serializer = AccountSerializer(transactions, many=True)

        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Not really understanding why this returns an error but if I put the account variable in the AccountSerializer it works fine.

Comment: Please add Account model, and also  account.transfers detailsl to the code so that we have better context to understand what is happening here.

Comment: @UmarHayat Hey have updated the post. Transfers is a property method that belongs to the Account model. I copied the wrong property method before but I have fixed it by adding the entire Account model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code's view method (`Transactions` class),

```py
transactions = account.transfers
serializer = AccountSerializer(transactions, many=True)
```

The `account.transfers` returns a list of `Ledger` objects which you are then passing to `AccountSerializer` but `AccountSerializer` is for serialization or de-serialization of `Account` model and not `Ledger`.

```py
class LedgerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Ledger
        fields = '__all__'
```

You need the above defined `LedgerSerializer` for your `Ledger` model and use this instead in your `Transactions` view.